# grep until the last url endpoint

Tags: awk, sed, grep

Let's say, I have file which contains the following links:

```
https://example.com/endpoint1
https://example.com/endpoint1/endpoint2/endpoint3
https://example.com/endpoint1/endpoint2
https://example.com/endpoint1/endpoint2/file.js
https://example.com/endpoint1/?url=test
```

and I need to grep until last endpoint, which in my case could be endpoint1 or endpoint2 or endpoint3.
I used `sed` and `awk`, but it matches the first match not the last

`cut -d / -f 1`

`awk -F_ '{print $1}'`

both command match only first `/`

Update:-
desired output is

```
https://example.com/endpoint1
https://example.com/endpoint1/endpoint2
https://example.com/endpoint1/endpoint2/endpoint3
```

any help!!

Comment: Try `sed -nE 's,.*/([^/?.]+)(/.*)?$,\1,p'`

Comment: hi @Cyrus, sorry i have updated it

Comment: Hi @WiktorStribiżew it extract only endpoints, i have updated the desired ouput , thanks for your help

Comment: Try `grep -oE '^https://[^/]+(/[^/.?]+)+$' file`, see [this online demo](https://ideone.com/UFOa3j).

Comment: How do you define an "endpoint"? Is it literally a string containing the word "endpoint" followed by a number or is it something else?

Comment: @EdMorton `endpoint` it just any word act as endpoint in url and it could be just alphabetical  OR alphanumeric

Comment: If `https://example.com/endpoint4/?url=test` existed in the input but `https://example.com/endpoint4` on it's own didn't exist, should `https://example.com/endpoint4` be printed or not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may consider this `awk` solution:

```sh
awk '{sub(/\/?\?.*|\/[^\/.]+\..[^\/]*$/, "")} !seen[$0]++' file

https://example.com/endpoint1
https://example.com/endpoint1/endpoint2/endpoint3
https://example.com/endpoint1/endpoint2
```

- `sub` function removes query string or last component of URL if it has `dot` in it.
- `!seen[$0]++` prints unique URLs skipping duplicates.

Comment: could you recommend any book related to awk magic :)

Answer (score 2):

One of the following may be what you're looking for, depending on the answer to [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67957283/grep-until-the-last-url-endpoint#comment120119897_67957283):

```
awk '($0 !~ "/[^/]*[^[:alnum:]/]+[^/]*$") && !seen[$0]++' file

awk '{sub("/[^/]*[^[:alnum:]/]+[^/]*$","")} !seen[$0]++' file
```

Both will behave the same and produce the output you provided from the input you provided but kook at the difference in behavior between the two given an additional input line:

```
$ cat file
https://example.com/endpoint1
https://example.com/endpoint1/endpoint2/endpoint3
https://example.com/endpoint1/endpoint2
https://example.com/endpoint1/endpoint2/file.js
https://example.com/endpoint1/?url=test
https://example.com/endpoint4/?url=test
```

```
$ awk '($0 !~ "/[^/]*[^[:alnum:]/]+[^/]*$") && !seen[$0]++' file
https://example.com/endpoint1
https://example.com/endpoint1/endpoint2/endpoint3
https://example.com/endpoint1/endpoint2
```

```
$ awk '{sub("/[^/]*[^[:alnum:]/]+[^/]*$","")} !seen[$0]++' file
https://example.com/endpoint1
https://example.com/endpoint1/endpoint2/endpoint3
https://example.com/endpoint1/endpoint2
https://example.com/endpoint4
```

Answer (score 1):

With your shown samples, please try following `awk` program. Setting field separator as `/` In case last field is either equals to dot OR ? then reduce number of fields and print line if that is already not listed in array. Then checking if last field is NOT equal to dot and `?`, then making sure only unique lines are getting printed by it.

```
awk '
BEGIN{
  FS=OFS="/"
}
($NF~/\./ || $NF~/\?/){
  NF--
  if(!seen[$0]++){ print }
}
($NF!~/\./ && $NF!~/\?/) && !seen[$0]++
' Input_file
```

---

---

***2nd solution:*** using `sed` + `sort` and using anubhava's answers regex here:

```
sed -E 's/\/?\?.*|\/[^\/.]+\..[^\/]*$//' Input_file | sort -u
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
cat yourdata.txt | egrep '^https://example\.com(/endpoint[1-3])+$'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
grep -Po '.*/endpoint[1-3](?=/|\r|$)' file | sort -u
```